# how to get a facebook friend location using web crawlers

Tags: android, facebook, nutch

I want to ask if there is any way I can get mine Facebook friends location using Nutch crawler or other open source web crawlers.

Answer (score 1):

- You can´t get any data of friends, friend permissions have been removed a long time ago and especially the location would be a major privacy issue.
- Crawling/Scraping is not allowed on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php